# How to use `request.formData()` in Node v20? (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, multipartform-data

When using NextJS, I've been able to use .formData() to generate a formData object from a request. When writing a simple ExpressJS app though, .formData() does not exist. I'd prefer not to use something like formidable or busboy. What do I have to change to be able to access this method?